# C# bring unassociated app to foreground

Tags: c#, foreground

I've been searching all over the net for answers to get a program to the foreground.  I've been doing it the ghetto way by sending alt-tab keystrokes with SendKeys.  I've tried this and it doesn't work,

```
private void execute()
{
    setApp("League of Legends.exe");
    Thread.Sleep(1500);
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
private static void setApp(String filename)
{
    Process[] SameProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName(filename);
    Process SameProcess = SameProcesses[0];
    if (SameProcess.Equals(null))
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("No process");
    }
    else
    { 
        SetForegroundWindow(SameProcess.MainWindowHandle); 
    }
}
```

Comment: What does not work? Do you see the message box?

Comment: probably you can find more info here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099479/restore-a-minimized-window-of-another-application

Comment: No the message box does not come up