# How can I bring the word application window is minisized to the front using C#?

Tags: vsto, setforegroundwindow

I'm developing a addin for office word using vsto. I'm trying to bring the word window that is minisized rebringing it to the front.I try to use winapi function `SwitchToThisWindow`、`SetForegroundWindow`, `SetWindowPos` like this

```
if (handlePtr != IntPtr.Zero)
{
    Win32API.SwitchToThisWindow(handlePtr, true);
    //Win32API.ShowWindow(handlePtr, Win32API.SW_MAXIMIZE);
    ////Win32API.SetForegroundWindow(handlePtr); 
    //Win32API.SetWindowPos(handlePtr, Win32API.HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0, Win32API.SWP_NOMOVE | Win32API.SWP_NOSIZE | Win32API.SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
}
```

and `Application.Activate()`, it works how every other function like this does and only makes it flash in taskbar instead of bringing it to the front.

Is there anyway to fix this? I also try to sendkeys ‘alt+tab’ but i don't know how to direct the word process window.

Comment: How do you retrieve the window handle? Note that your question may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099479/restore-a-minimized-window-of-another-application

Comment: You are right,i get the main window handle is by getting current process's MainWindowHandle.I think it had changed when is minimized.But the question is how can i get word's mainwindowhandle when word addin's Ribbon_Load function is excuting.

Comment: I have to try to call winapi findow("NetUIHWND",null)  and get result is 0.The class NetUIHWND is by using spy++ to get.

Comment: The `MainWindowHandle` can easily cause problems: it may no longer be valid, e.g. if the first document is closed, or you get the wrong window if several documents are open. It is better to use the `Window.Hwnd` property, e.g. via `Application.ActiveDocument.Window[1].Hwnd` or `Application.ActiveWindow`.

Comment: Thanks,I fund a another way of working. this is my code: `WordApplication.Activate();
            WordApplication.Visible = true;
            WordApplication.ActiveDocument.Activate();

            IntPtr winfrom = IntPtr.Zero; 
            if (GetNEClientRunningState(out winfrom))
            {
                Win32API.SwitchToThisWindow(winfrom, true); 
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30); 
                SendKeys.SendWait("%{TAB}");
            } `

Comment: Hi dirk,i get another serious trouble,it can not active the last active document when opening many word document. I have try to use your suggest code `Application.ActiveDocument.Window[1].Hwnd` and `Application.ActiveWindow`.Sorry for the inconvenience! This is my code `IntPtr handlePtr = new IntPtr(WordApplication.ActiveDocument.Windows[1].Hwnd);Win32API.SwitchToThisWindow(handlePtr, true);Win32API.ShowWindow(handlePtr, Win32API.SW_MAXIMIZE);Win32API.SetForegroundWindow(handlePtr)`